# Mapbox React Native can't access the map's methods

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

This is probably basic, but I'm getting tripped up with the documentation between the JS Mapbox and the React Native Mapbox. I'm creating a new map instance by importing mapbox into my project via `import Mapbox from '@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl';`
 and then in the render() function I'm loading the map via:

```
<View style={container}>
    <Mapbox.MapView
        styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Light}
        zoomLevel={12}
        centerCoordinate={[lat, lng]}
        style={styles.container}
        showUserLocation
    >
    {this.renderAnnotations()}
    </Mapbox.MapView>
</View>
```

The `renderAnnotations()` function I've defined as follows:

```
renderAnnotations() {
        return this.state.stations.map((station, index) =>
          <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._map.flyTo.bind(this, station)} key={index}>
            <View ref={component => this._root = component}>
              <StationPoint key={station.id} station={station} />
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        );
      }
```

The goal is for it to render points on the map with a corresponding flyTo onPress event. The map and these points render perfectly fine, but the onpress event returns:

> error "Cannot read property 'flyTo' of undefined"

On [this](https://blog.kevinchisholm.com/react-native/mapbox-sdk-fly-to/) tutorial, it suggests you can access the map using this._map. Is this correct and I'm making a different error? Or is there an alternative way for accessing the map methods? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the answer, in case it helps someone else. I wasn't defining a `ref` property on the MapView. It should have had a reference defined as `this._map` like the following:

```
<View style={container}>
    <Mapbox.MapView
        ref={(c) => this._map = c}
        styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Light}
        zoomLevel={12}
        centerCoordinate={[lat, lng]}
        style={styles.container}
        showUserLocation
    >
    {this.renderAnnotations()}
    </Mapbox.MapView>
</View>
```